# Obtener datos por longitud de fecha

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy utilizando between para obtener una lista con resultados puestos en las fechas

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM carga_valijas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$valija1' AND '$valija2'")
```

La cosa es que quiero obtener los datos obtenidos desde la fecha puesta y hasta la fecha puesta pero me esta mostrando los datos de las fechas colocadas

Es decir, si en las variable existe

```
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '20-08-2020' AND '23-09-2020'
```

En vez de obtener los resultados:

Fechas:

20-08-2020

21-08-2020

22-09-2020

23-09-2020

Me omite  `21-08-2020` y `22-09-2020`

Estoy realizando algo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser por que los valores de tus fechas estan como cadenas intenta convirtiendolas a formato fecha con la funcion `STR_TO_DATE`.

Ejemplo:

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM carga_valijas WHERE fecha BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$valija1', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$valija2', '%d-%m-%Y')")
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, asi me ahorro algunas lineas

Comment: aunque por error de mi parte no coloque el el campo fecha como tipo date y por eso no me agarraba aunque con tu codigo me  ahorre unas cosas